# X-Accel-Redirect works from outside, but not from inside

Tags: php, nginx, dokku, x-accel-redirect

So here's my thing. Got a php app running on nginx/dokku.

I have a location which is redirecting image assets. Say:

```
https://test.rokfor.ch/cdn/dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff
```

Results in a image, shown in the Browser.

Calling the same resource within a php script like:

```
header('X-Accel-Redirect: /cdn/dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff');
exit(0);
```

Results in an internal error. Nginx config looks like:

```
location ~ ^/cdn/(.*?)/(.*) {
  resolver 8.8.8.8;
  proxy_set_header HOST $1;
  proxy_pass "https://$1/$2?$args";
}
```

What could be potiential issues? Since I don't know in which direction to look.

Comment: What's in the error log?

Comment: I get an `2016/10/03 12:20:59 [error] 249#0: *47 invalid URL prefix in "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff`. It seems that it is somehow related to ssl: if I change the location to `proxy_pass "http://$1/$2?$args";` (without https) it seems to work. But it does not help me - I need https!

Comment: Whenever I'd like to change something within the `location`directive, I get errors like `nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "proxy_ssl_server_name" in /app/nginx_app.conf:6`... Nginx is compiled `--with-http_ssl_module` and version 1.10 built with OpenSSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - found it out:

Dokku runs internally Nginx 1.8 without SSL support. Proxy_pass to https therefore *cannot* work. I managed to work around the problem by forking the original heroku php buildpack, pushed the nginx dependency to 1.10 and added an additional repository providing a nginx version built with ssl support.